# change point size in WPFToolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

i try to change point size in wpf toolkit

```
<charting:Chart Name="Charts" Margin="87,48,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
        <charting:LineSeries Name="ChartOne" DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" Title="График функции" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast"/>
        <charting:Chart.Axes>
            <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Y" ShowGridLines="True" Minimum="0"/>
            <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="X" ShowGridLines="True" Minimum="0"/>
        </charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </charting:Chart>
```

but i have an error "The attachable property 'DataPointStyle' was not found in type 'LineSeries'"
what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid>
    <charting:Chart Name="Charts" Margin="87,48,0,0" Grid.Column="1">

        <charting:Chart.Axes>
            <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Y" ShowGridLines="True" Minimum="0"/>
            <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="X" ShowGridLines="True" Minimum="0"/>
        </charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LineSeries Name="ChartOne" DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" 
                             Title="График функции" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast">
        <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </charting:LineSeries>
   </charting:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Error 'chartingToolkit' is an undeclared prefix.

Comment: Have you add the reference assembly? @KonstantinMokhov

Comment: i download wpf.msi from http://wpf.codeplex.com/ and install it. i haven't WPF Toolkit Extended in "Add reference"!

Comment: in add reference window there is a tab "Browse" from there u can browse and add the reference

Comment: Once the assembly reference is added, the next step is to import the namespace in XAML using the xmlns                                        https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/99072

Comment: Ok. i add Xceed.WPF.Toolkit.dll - but before adding in namespace error - Error The tag 'LineSeries.DataPointStyle' does not exist in XML namespace clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit'

Comment: This is correct answer. Important thing to notice is that you have to put `LineSeries.DataPointStyle` tag **inside** the `LineSeries` tag. `<charting:LineSeries ...> <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>...</charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle></charting:LineSeries>`